# Reduce the time to find six integer numbers so that the angle of two vectors equal to Pi/6

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find six integer numbers `a, b, c, x, y, z` so that the angle of two vector `{a, b, c` and `{x, y, z}` equal to `Pi/6`. I tried

```
Clear[a, b, c]
u = {x, y, z};
v = {a, b, c};
list = {u, v} /. 
   Solve[{4*(a*x + b*y + c*z)^2 == 
      3*(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), a b c x y z != 0, a > x, 
     0 < a*x + b*y + c*z, GCD[a, b, c] == 1, GCD[x, y, z] == 1, 
     Sequence @@ Thread[0 < {a, b, c, x, y, z} < 15]}, {x, y, z, a, b,
      c}, Integers];
Select[list, (6 == Length[Union @@ #] &)]
```

If I use

```
Sequence @@ Thread[0 < {a, b, c, x, y, z} < 9]}
```

I got

> {{{1, 2, 7}, {4, 3, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {5, 2, 7}}, {{1, 4, 3}, {5, 7,
> 2}}, {{1, 7, 2}, {4, 5, 3}}, {{1, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 5}}, {{1, 8,
> 7}, {3, 5, 2}}, {{2, 1, 7}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{2, 3, 5}, {7, 1,
> 8}}, {{2, 5, 3}, {7, 8, 1}}, {{2, 5, 7}, {3, 1, 4}}, {{2, 7,
> 1}, {3, 5, 4}}, {{2, 7, 5}, {3, 4, 1}}, {{4, 1, 3}, {7, 5,
> 2}}, {{4, 3, 1}, {7, 2, 5}}, {{5, 2, 3}, {8, 7, 1}}, {{5, 3,
> 2}, {8, 1, 7}}, {{5, 3, 4}, {7, 2, 1}}, {{5, 4, 3}, {7, 1, 2}}}

The time is longer If I use

```
Sequence @@ Thread[0 < {a, b, c, x, y, z} < 15]}
```

How can I reduce timing?

Comment: Your results have an angle of Pi/6 not Pi/3. You should use 2 and 1 as coefficients  rather than 4 and 3.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @DanielHuber I think 4 and 1 as coefficients rather than 4 and 3 (if angle of Pi/3).

Comment: Yes, you are right it of Cos[]^2 not Cos[]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
n = 15;
expr = 4*(a*x + b*y + c*z)^2 - 3*(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
set = Permutations[Range[n], {6}];
pick = Pick[set, Unitize@NDSolve`FEM`ApplyToCoordinates[expr, {a,b,c,x,y,z}, set], 0];
ans = pick // Map[Partition[#, 3] &] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort] //
      Select[AllTrue[GCD @@ # == 1 &]]

Length[ans]
AbsoluteTime[] - t1
```

> {{{1, 2, 7}, {4, 3, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {5, 2, 7}}, {{1, 4, 3}, {5, 7,
> 2}}, {{1, 4, 9}, {11, 13, 14}}, {{1, 5, 6}, {7, 4, 11}}, {{1, 6,
> 5}, {7, 11, 4}}, {{1, 6, 7}, {8, 5, 13}}, {{1, 7, 2}, {4, 5,
> 3}}, {{1, 7, 6}, {8, 13, 5}}, {{1, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 5}}, {{1, 7,
> 10}, {4, 3, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 5, 2}}, {{1, 9, 4}, {11, 14,
> 13}}, {{1, 10, 7}, {4, 5, 3}}, {{1, 10, 11}, {4, 3, 7}}, {{1, 11,
> 10}, {4, 7, 3}}, {{1, 13, 14}, {5, 4, 9}}, {{1, 14, 13}, {5, 9,
> 4}}, {{2, 1, 7}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{2, 3, 5}, {7, 1, 8}}, {{2, 5,
> 3}, {7, 8, 1}}, {{2, 5, 7}, {3, 1, 4}}, {{2, 7, 1}, {3, 5,
> 4}}, {{2, 7, 5}, {3, 4, 1}}, {{2, 11, 13}, {5, 3, 8}}, {{2, 13,
> 11}, {5, 8, 3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {7, 1, 10}}, {{3, 4, 7}, {10, 1,
> 11}}, {{3, 5, 4}, {7, 10, 1}}, {{3, 5, 8}, {11, 2, 13}}, {{3, 7,
> 4}, {10, 11, 1}}, {{3, 8, 5}, {11, 13, 2}}, {{4, 1, 3}, {7, 5,
> 2}}, {{4, 1, 9}, {13, 11, 14}}, {{4, 3, 1}, {7, 2, 5}}, {{4, 5,
> 9}, {13, 1, 14}}, {{4, 7, 11}, {5, 1, 6}}, {{4, 9, 1}, {13, 14,
> 11}}, {{4, 9, 5}, {13, 14, 1}}, {{4, 11, 7}, {5, 6, 1}}, {{5, 2,
> 3}, {8, 7, 1}}, {{5, 3, 2}, {8, 1, 7}}, {{5, 3, 4}, {7, 2,
> 1}}, {{5, 3, 4}, {10, 7, 1}}, {{5, 4, 3}, {7, 1, 2}}, {{5, 4,
> 3}, {10, 1, 7}}, {{5, 8, 13}, {6, 1, 7}}, {{5, 13, 8}, {6, 7,
> 1}}, {{6, 1, 5}, {11, 7, 4}}, {{6, 5, 1}, {11, 4, 7}}, {{7, 1,
> 6}, {13, 8, 5}}, {{7, 3, 4}, {11, 10, 1}}, {{7, 4, 3}, {11, 1,
> 10}}, {{7, 6, 1}, {13, 5, 8}}, {{8, 3, 5}, {13, 11, 2}}, {{8, 5,
> 3}, {13, 2, 11}}, {{9, 1, 4}, {14, 11, 13}}, {{9, 4, 1}, {14, 13,
> 11}}, {{9, 4, 5}, {14, 13, 1}}, {{9, 5, 4}, {14, 1, 13}}}
>
> 60
>
> 0.4529855

Comment: How can I get triple `[a,b,c]` or `[x,y,z]` with `GCD[a,b,c]==1` and `GCD[x,y,z]==1`?

Comment: I can not get the result with
`expr = 4*(a*x + b*y + c*z)^2 - 2*(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2);`

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Well, see my update. It seems that `CoprimeQ[a,b,c]` and `GCD[a,b,c]==1` are not strictly equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you can allow an upper limit for the components, we may simply check all possibilities. As the angle of Pi/3 is less than Pi, we may restrict the search to one quadrant. Further solutions may be obtained by reflection at the coordinate planes.

```
n = 10;
res = Reap[
   Do[
    If[4 ({j1, j2, j3}.{i1, i2, i3})^2 == {i1, i2, i3}.{i1, i2, 
         i3} {j1, j2, j3}.{j1, j2, j3}, Sow[{i1, i2, i3, j1, j2, j3}]]
    , {i1, n}, {i2, n}, {i3, n}, {j1, n}, {j2, n}, {j3, n}]
   ][[2, 1]]
```

This results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since `FindInstance` hasn't yet been mentioned (though it's not that fast):

```
sol = First@
   FindInstance[{a, b, c} . {x, y, z} == 
     Norm[{a, b, c}] Norm[{x, y, z}] Cos[Pi/6], {a, b, c, x, y, z}, 
    PositiveIntegers];
Column[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}} /. sol]
VectorAngle[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}] /. sol

(** {11, 2, 19}
    {1, 1, 140} **)
```